# Making a list view popup

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview, jquery-mobile-popup

I am trying to make a very basic listview popup. I just cant seen to get it working. Here is the code I have so far

```
        <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="map"></div>
            <a href="#filter" class="map_buttons" id="map_filter_button" data-rel="dialog">Filter</a>
            <a href="#menu" class="map_buttons" id="map_manu_button" data-rel="dialog">Menu</a>
            <a href="#report_popupMenu" class="map_buttons" id="map_report_button" data-rel="popup" data-inline="true" data-transition="slideup">Report</a>
        </div>
    </div>

<div id="report_popupMenu" data-role="popup">
    <ul id="report_categories" data-role="listview" data-inset="true\" style="width:210px;">
        <li data-role=\"divider\" data-theme=\"b\">Choose Category.</li>
        <li  data-theme=\"b\">Choose Category.</li>
        <li  data-theme=\"b\">Choose Category.</li>
        <li data-theme=\"b\">Choose Category.</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="report_popupMenu" data-role="popup">
    <ul id="report_categories" data-role="listview" data-inset="true\" style="width:210px;">
        <li data-role=\"divider\" data-theme=\"b\">Choose Category.</li>
        <li  data-theme=\"b\">Choose Category.</li>
        <li  data-theme=\"b\">Choose Category.</li>
        <li data-theme=\"b\">Choose Category.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Im using the following CDNs

I want the popup to be at the centre of the screen. What i have done has been following this site http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/popup/#&ui-state=dialog but its just not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the code that is being usred to load the

s from  the config file

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var map = null;
init();
popuateCat();
function init() {
    var mapProp = {
        center : new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850),
        zoom : 5,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        disableDefaultUI : true,
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapProp);

}

function popuateCat() {

    $.ajax({
        url : "configs/reportCatagories.config",
        dataType : "xml",
        success : function(data) {
        $("#report_categories").append("<li data-role=\"divider\" data-theme=\"b\">Choose Category.</li>");
            $(data).find("Category").each(function() {
                var dataString = $(this).text();
                var cat = '<li><a href=\"#newReport\" id=\"' + dataString + '\">' + dataString + '</a></li>';
                $("#report_categories").append(cat);
            });
        }
    });

}
```

});

Comment: you have duplicated popups `id="report_popupMenu"` it'll never work.

Answer (score 3):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/QGhYN/

Attribute **`data-position-to="window"`** is added to popup div. It will center popup.

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
        <h1>Index page</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#report_popupMenu" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="pop">Basic Popup</a>
        <div id="report_popupMenu" data-role="popup" data-position-to="window">
            <ul id="report_categories" data-role="listview" data-inset="true\" style="width:210px;">
                <li data-role=\"divider\" data-theme=\"b\">Choose Category.</li>
                <li  data-theme=\"b\">Choose Category.</li>
                <li  data-theme=\"b\">Choose Category.</li>
                <li data-theme=\"b\">Choose Category.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, you have to place the popup div's inside the page div.
Like this:

```
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="popup">
  </div>
</div>
```

I believe yours aren't inside the page div, check your closing div tags.

Comment: thats just a double paste sorry. Its not actually in the code

Comment: Ok, if you still need it here's a working fiddle with your code and the categories popup is centered.
http://jsfiddle.net/Pt75w/

Comment: Thanks guys. Im almost there. But im  loading from all the stuff that will go into the <ul> from a config file. I am finding that when the page is done loading the stuff in the <ul> ie list items are just in plain text and not displayed as list views. Any pointers?

Comment: As long as your ul has a 'data-role="listview"' it should be fine. Are you sure that the li's are appended to the ul correctly? Or maybe the "stuff" from the config file is loaded before the jquerymobile script is loaded?

Comment: I think its loading before jquery. If i put some list items in manually they show up perfectly but if I use my AJAX method to update its not formated properly. But isnt $.ajax part of JQUERYso jquery is fine by this time its the JQUERYMOBILE files I think.

Comment: Im using the code i have just edited into the question. The funcction is called just after my google maps api. I have also tried to  delay the Jax call but it didnt work even though all was loaded by ten seconds

Comment: Could you post your javascript code somewhere so I can take a look? And the order of your script tags in the html page as well.

Comment: Does every list item look like plain text or is it only those with data? $("#report_categories").append(cat);
I had a quick look and didn't really see a problem, I'll come back in a few hours and I'll try to help.